# Downgrade a package installed from source

Tags: apt, package-management, downgrade

I'm trying to install a specific version of the library as follows,

```
sudo apt-get install -f libvtk6.3
```

But, I have got an existing latest version of the same library installed in my system from source hence it fires up the following error,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libvtk6.3 is already the newest version (6.3.0+dfsg1-11build1).
```

How do I downgrade it forcefully?

Comment: I'm confused, you say you installed it 'from source' - did you install it via `dpkg` or install it by hand manually?  `dpkg` and `apt-get` do NOT get information regarding source-compiled software.

Comment: I don't see any error there.  That is a message.  Also, to see all the versions available of an app use `apt-cache madison libvtk6.3` then to install a specific version it is just `sudo apt install libvtk6.3=6.3.0+dfsg1-11build1` or whatever version is available.